# Hyperlinks in d3.js objects

Tags: d3.js

I am a complete novice at d3.js or java in general. I am using the indented tree example from http://bl.ocks.org/1093025. It took me two hours to get this to work on my local computer, so that should give you an idea of my skill level.

I opened the flare.json file and started messing with it and was able to manipulate it successfully. It looks like this

```
{
    "name": "Test D3",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "News",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "CNN",
                    "size": 1000
                },
                {
                    "name": "BBC",
                    "size": 3812
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Blogs",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Engaget",
                    "size": 3938
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Search",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Google",
                    "size": 3938
                },
                {
                    "name": "Bing",
                    "size": 3938
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want to do now, is to try to add hyperlinks. For example, I want to be able to click on "CNN" and go to CNN.com. Is there a modification I can make to flare.json that will do that?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It is quite easy, just add some more "key" : "value" pairs. Example:

```
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Google",
                "size": 3938,
                "url":  "https://www.google.com"

            },
            {
                "name": "Bing",
                "size": 3938,
                "url":  "http://www.bing.com"

            }
        ]
```

Of course, in your d3 code you then need to `append` `<svg:a>` tags and set their `xlink:href` attribute.

Here is some html and d3-code that might be of help to you. First you need to import the xlink namespace in your html file:

```
<html xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
...
</html>
```

Then in the d3 drawing code where you append nodes for each data element you wrap the element you want to be clickable links with an `svg:a` tag:

```
nodeEnter.append("svg:a")
  .attr("xlink:href", function(d){return d.url;})  // <-- reading the new "url" property
.append("svg:rect")
  .attr("y", -barHeight / 2)
  .attr("height", barHeight)
  .attr("width", barWidth)
  .style("fill", color)
  .on("click", click);  // <- remove this if you like
```

You might want to remove the click handler (which is present in the original example)  by deleting the .on("click", click) as it might interfere with the default behavior of SVG links.

Clicking on your `rect`s should now lead you to the appropriate `url`.
SVG links might not be fully implemented in all browsers.

Alternatively you could modify the `click` handler to read the URL from `d.url` and use that one to manually redirect the browser to that URL via JavaScript: `window.location = d.url;`. Then you do not need the `svg:a` tag and the `xlink` code. Though adding a real link (not a scripted one) has the benefit that the user/browser can decide what to do (e.g., open in new tab/page). It also helps if some of your users have JavaScript disabled.

Comment: Regarding which **browsers** are **supporting SVG links**, take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28Scalable_Vector_Graphics%29

Comment: Note that at least in Chrome you don't need to declare any namespaces anywhere and in D3.js v3 you can just write `.append('a')` instead of `.append('svg:a')`. However, you still need to write `xlink:href`. If you still want the namespaces in the DOM, it seems you now have to use [this hack](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/d3-js/Sh4ysLFBMRQ/hHjzBP0bX1oJ) to keep them from disappearing when you insert them with D3.js.

Comment: Can you please add a demo of this. Please i need it badly.

Comment: A plunker showing working hyperlinks (click on a node rectangle to go to cnn): http://plnkr.co/edit/D4xy4x?p=preview

Comment: How to add the hyperlink after the element was created in D3? I have a selection with various circles and need to attach an hyperlink to each. I tried the proposed solution, but I think it assumes we are adding D3 objects after the "<a href>" element is created? I am not proficient in web programming, any help is appreciated.