# Hyperlinks in this NVD3 example

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

http://nvd3.org/ghpages/scatter.html

I want to make each little data (circle) a clickable link. My real intention is to make each datapoint have a modal window popup, but for now I'll just start with a link, to make it easier as I am a beginner.

I found this link [Hyperlinks in d3.js objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104681/hyperlinks-in-d3-js-objects)

and have tried to modify the code.

here is my dataset, as you can see i added the key/element (not sure which it is) "url" and have specified a link.

```
var data = [{key: 'Group1', values: [{x: 1, y: 1, url:"https:google.com"}, {x: -2, y: 3}, {x: 4, y: -9}]},
            {key: 'Group2', values: [{x: 2, y: 0}, {x: -4, y: -4}, {x: 1, y: 8}]}];

  return data;
```

Then following the first link, I pasted this into the html of the code

```
nodeEnter.append("svg:a")
  .attr("xlink:href", function(d){return d.url;})  // <-- reading the new "url" property
.append("svg:rect")
  .attr("y", -barHeight / 2)
  .attr("height", barHeight)
  .attr("width", barWidth)
  .style("fill", color)
  .on("click", click);  // <- remove this if you like
```

But it is not working, I guess it is the nvd3 not being compatible with pure d3 code. Could anybody help me with possibly an example of the code i would need to do this ?

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [source code](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/scatter.js) of nvd3 scatter plots you will see that there are multiple parameters you can set but not this one.

Nvd3 is a library providing re-usable charts, which means they provide a whole bunch of functionalities, but you have some limits due to what is public or not even if they try to have as much functionalities as possible. What you try to do in your code won't work because you don't have any direct control on that when calling the nvd3 scatter chart.

However, there is a good news: Nvd3 is open source, so you can modify the source of scatter.js in order to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the source code and comment the pointer-events line

```
div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;   
  text-align: center;   
  width: 60px;  
  height: 28px;     
  padding: 2px; 
  font: 12px sans-serif;    
  background: lightsteelblue;   
  border: 0px;                  
  border-radius: 8px;
 /*  pointer-events: none;  This line needs to be removed */

}
```

For more information, see [this](https://gist.github.com/d3noob/c37cb8e630aaef7df30d) link.