# d3.js - How to add url link in for collapsible indented tree

Tags: d3.js

I have the data in JSON like this:

```
{
 "name": "OSS Applications",
 "children": [
  {
     "name": "ELITE 3E",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Elite 3E Mobile Gateway"},
      {"name": "Elite 3E Mobile Website"},
      {"name": "Elite 3E Mobile Application"}

     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "WESTLAW DOC & FORM BUILDER",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Cobalt Website WFB"},
      {"name": "Cobalt Static Content WFB"},
      {"name": "Cobalt Search WFA"},
      {"name": "Cobalt Forms Assembly WFB"},
      {"name": "Cobalt Foldering WFB"}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "FINDLAW.COM",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Findlaw-Infirmation"},
      {"name": "Findlaw-hippocms"},
      {"name": "Findlaw-Lawyers Directory"},
      {"name": "Findlaw-ProfileUpdate"},
      {"name": "Findlaw-Pview"},
    {"name": "Findlaw-RCMS"},
    {"name": "Findlaw-public-channel"}
     ]
    }
 ]
}
```

I would like to add a url link  to the applications "ELITE 3E", "WESTLAW DOC & FORM BUILDER" and "FINDLAW.com". How do i do that? I am trying to replicate the collapsible indented tree. mbostock’s block #1093025

Comment: You can use an [SVG link](http://www.w3.org/wiki/SVG_Links).

Comment: Thanks Lars.... I got a similar example from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104681/hyperlinks-in-d3-js-objects. However how do i open the href in a seperate tab instead of the same window

Comment: Specify `target="_blank"`.

Comment: Where exactly in the code should i specify. Can i add one more label in the json for this or do i need to code the same in the html?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. This would be another attribute for the `a` element.

Comment: Got it!!! thanks Lars. If you can reply i can flag it as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an [SVG link](http://www.w3.org/wiki/SVG_Links) to achieve this. All you need to do is add an `a` element around the element that you want to act as the link, e.g.

```
svg.append("a")
   .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.url; })
   .append("circle")
   //etc
```

To make the link open in a new window, set the `target` attribute to `_blank`:

```
svg.append("a")
   .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.url; })
   .attr("target", "_blank")
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to add the link as below, you can add attr onclick.

```
<text x="7" y="20" style="font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:white;fill:white;" zIndex="1">
    <tspan onclick="location.href="http://target.url.com"" style="cursor: pointer;" x="7">URL TEXT</tspan>
</text>
```

And another way, you can bind click event to achieve it.

```
svg.selectAll('.add-url-node')
   .on('click',function(d){
       location.href = 'target.url.com';
   });
```