# Adding an <a> tag before the primary data element in the enter() section of a selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Using d3.js, I'm working with a selection that use enter(), exit() and the default update selection.
The elements of my selection are sag:path elements.  When I create them, I want to create them surrounded by an  tag.  When I update them, I only want to update the  element within.

I'm trying the below, but the update section is being performed on the  tags.  e.g. I end up with "display" & "stroke" attributes on the  tag.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13109162/213042) deals with adding an a tag, but not the update confusion.

How I am supposed to do this?

```
var preciseLinks = svg.selectAll("path.preciseLink")
        .data(json, function(d) { return d["r1"]["title"] + "-" + d["r1"]["loc"] + "-" + d["r2"]["title"] + "-" + d["r2"]["loc"]; });

    //enter
    preciseLinks.enter()
            .append("a").attr("href", function(d) { return "/" + replaceAll(d["r1"]["title"],"-","_") + "." + replaceAll(d["r1"]["loc"],":",".")})
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", function(d) { return "preciseLink " + d["r1"]["title"] + " " + d["r2"]["title"]; });

    //update
    preciseLinks
            .attr("display", "inline")
            .attr("stroke", function (d) { ...
```

Comment: In your `//update` section, you can refine your selection to select only the paths: `preciseLinks.selectAll("path").attr("display", ..`

Comment: Josh's comment and Mike's answer are spot on.  A side note: The "href" element here needs an "xlink" namespace to work correctly: "xlink:href" is the correct form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be consistent with the base element of your selection. If you want to have `<a><path></path></a>` for each data point, you'll want to use `<a>` as the base of your selection, and select inwards from there in your update.

```
var preciseLinks = svg.selectAll("a.preciseLinkA")
        .data(json, function(d) { return d["r1"]["title"] + "-" + d["r1"]["loc"] + "-" + d["r2"]["title"] + "-" + d["r2"]["loc"]; });

    //enter
    preciseLinks.enter()
            .append("a").attr("href", function(d) { return "/" + replaceAll(d["r1"]["title"],"-","_") + "." + replaceAll(d["r1"]["loc"],":",".")})
            .classed("preciseLinkA", true)
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", function(d) { return "preciseLink " + d["r1"]["title"] + " " + d["r2"]["title"]; });

    //update
    preciseLinks
            .select("path.preciseLink")
            .attr("display", "inline")
            .attr("stroke", function (d) { ...
```

Comment: Yup.  That does it.  Thank you!