# D3: Hyperlinks in tree diagram

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, hyperlink

I'm having trouble hyperlinking child elements in a Reingold-Tifold tree graph. The graph is built in D3 and is based on the one that Mike Bostock uses an example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339184

My code and a segment of my JSON file are below.

At this point, the graph works fine - if I click on a parent node, it expands to reveal a series of child nodes that are contained in my JSON file. But when I get to the child level, I want to make the word hyperlinked. I don't understand how to do that.

I've used a previous SO question/answer - [Hyperlinks in d3.js objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104681/hyperlinks-in-d3-js-objects) - to understand how to add a URL to my JSON data (at this point everything is just linking to Google.co.uk). But I don't understand how to link that URL to my tree graph so that the child nodes become hyperlinked.

Can you let me know how I can do this?

Thank you, in advance, for any help. (And thanks, @IH8, for your assistance so far.)

Matt

```
<html xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<head><meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #FF0000;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 11px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #FF0000;

  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<style id="style-1-cropbar-clipper">/* Copyright 2014 Evernote Corporation. All rights reserved. */
.en-markup-crop-options {
    top: 18px !important;
    left: 50% !important;
    margin-left: -100px !important;
    width: 200px !important;
    border: 2px rgba(255,255,255,.38) solid !important;
    border-radius: 4px !important;
}

.en-markup-crop-options div div:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 0px !important;
}
</style></head><body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("/sites/default/files/tcs/D3/data/turbo.json", function(error, turbo) {
  root = turbo;
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

  function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }

  root.children.forEach(collapse);
  update(root);
});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "red" : "#fff"; });


  nodeEnter.each(function(d){
    var thisNode = d3.select(this);
    if (!d.children) {
        thisNode.append("a")
            .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.url; })
            .append("text")
                .attr("x", 8)
                .attr("dy", 3)
                .attr("text-anchor", "start")
                .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
    } else {
        thisNode.append("text")
            .attr("x", -8)
            .attr("dy", 3)
            .attr("text-anchor", "end")
            .text(function(d) { return d.name; });      
    }
});


  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "red" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

A portion of my JSON file:

```
{
 "name": "turbo",


 "children": [
  {

   "name": "Level 1",
   "children": [

    {
     "name": "Google",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Website", "size": 3938, "URL":"http://www.google.co.uk"},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812, "URL":"http://www.google.co.uk"},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714, "URL":"http://www.google.co.uk"},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743, "URL":"http://www.google.co.uk"}
     ]
    },

    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534, "URL":"http://www.google.co.uk"},
      {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731, "URL":"http://www.google.co.uk"},
      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840, "URL":"http://www.google.co.uk"},
      {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914, "URL":"http://www.google.co.uk"},
      {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416, "URL":"http://www.google.co.uk"}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "optimization",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074, "URL":"http://www.google.co.uk"}
     ]
    }
   ]
  }, 
. . .
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems you've made a slight mistake when creating your dataset url attribute, or you should've adapted the code you're using to add the xlink:href attribute to the a element. You're calling:

```
.attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.url; })
```

But in your dataset the attribute defined like this:

```
"URL": "http://www.google.co.uk"
```

Those don't match, you should change your code to this:

```
.attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.URL; })
```

Or your dataset to this:

```
 "url": "http://www.google.co.uk"
```

Remember that names of JSON properties are case-sensitive.