# How add a link to each shape in d3 radar chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Bellow is my code snippet,I have integrated the d3 radar chart in my project and  I just want to add a link to each shape drawn in radar chart. any help would be much appreciated. please help.
Bellow is my code snippet,I have integrated the d3 radar chart in my project and  I just want to add a link to each shape drawn in radar chart. any help would be much appreciated. please help.

```
 **GET JSON FOR GETTING DATA FROM SERVER**


 function get_jsons1(page,divid,formid)
    {
            // $('#radar').html("");
            //alert("sfdsfdsf")
            $('#radar_legend').html("");
            $('#radar').html("");
            $('#test1').html(""); 
            $('#test2').html(""); 
            $('#test3').html(""); 
            $('#test4').html("");  
                $('#test5').html(""); 
                $('#links').html("");
                $("#search-month").html("");
               $('#total').html("No result found");
            var formvalues = do_it(formid);    
            url_page       = page;
            formvalues=formvalues.substring(1,formvalues.length); 
            // Call to check the status of global variable (is_csrf) and existence of token.
            temp_array     = [];
            temp_rr        = [];
            type_shape     = {};
            temp_array7    = []; 
            temp_array14   = []; 
            temp_array22   = []; 
            temp_array28   = [];
            temp_array32   = [];
            var params     = "";

            var cct = check_token();
            // Check if global variable is false or if its true but the token is not existed.
            if(cct == 0)
            {
                var params=formvalues+'&';
            }
            else
            {
                var params=formvalues+'&ci_csrf_token='+cct;
            }                             

            /*load loading image*/
            document.getElementById('loader').innerHTML ='<div align="center"><image src="/hrmis/images/loading.gif" border="0"></div>';     

            $.ajax({  
            dataType: "json",           
            url:      url_page,
            type:     'POST',
            data:     params,
            success:  function(response)
            {       

        $('#radar_legend').html("");
        var cur_type =[]; 
        $.each( response, function(key,val) 
        {
            if(val.pagination)
            {
                   //pagination
                    $.each( val.pagination, function(k,v) 
                    { 

                        if(v.links != 0)
                        {
                           $('#links').html(v.links);    
                        }
                        //$('#links').html(v.links);
                        $('#total').html(v.total);
                    });
            }
             $("#search-month").html(val.option); 
            var hours = []; 



            //== set parameters of form to temperary varible to send latar to server           
            param=val.param;  



            //$("#search-month").html(val.option);
            $("#search-month select").val(selected); 
            $.each( val.point, function(k,v) 
            {                                   

                if(temp_rr.length > 0)
                {
                    var temph =null;
                    $.each( hours, function(ss,hh)
                    {
                        temph = hh;
                        if(hh == v.hour)
                        {

                            temph = (v.hour);
                        }
                    });

                    temp_rr.push({axis:v.day,value:temph,color:v.color,label:v.c_type+"  ::   "+v.date_title+" ( "+v.urn+" ) ",shape:v.shape});
                    hours.push(v.hour); 
                }
                else
                {   
                    temp_rr.push({axis:v.day,value:v.hour,color:v.color,label:v.c_type+"  ::   "+v.date_title+" ( "+v.urn+" ) ",shape:v.shape});
                    hours.push(v.hour); 
                } 

                ///////////legend
                if(cur_type.indexOf(v.c_type)==-1)
                {   

                    get_rdr_legend(v,temp_rr);
                }
                cur_type.push(v.c_type);



        });              
        var final_rr = [temp_rr];
        console.log(JSON.stringify(final_rr));
        $('#radar').html(""); 
        RadarChart.draw("#radar", final_rr, mycfg);
             //==== remove the loader GIF 
              $("#loader").remove();
              $("#con_loader").append("<div id='loader'></div>"); 

            },   
            error:function(msg)
            {
                alert("error finding page");
            }
            });

        }
```

[image: radarchart]

Answer (score 0):

Although the tag mentioned d3, there is no d3 code in your example.

When you start to use de d3 library you can add a link to any drawn object as in [Hyperlinks in d3.js objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104681/hyperlinks-in-d3-js-objects)