# D3 #4063269 Clickable nodes

Tags: d3.js, click

I am trying to make a D3 layout have a click event. I am working on Mike Bostock's Bubble Chart, found here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269 .

I want to have the JSON file nodes clickable to several HTTP addresses. I think that the code needed is in the JSON could be:

```
{"name": "Visualization", "address": "https://github.com/", "size": 16540}
```

I have seen this on other D3 visualizations and I am trying to apply this to the bubble chart. Do I need to add some code to the index.html page? I am asking this because when I add the address attribute and a http web address, it does not work.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104681/hyperlinks-in-d3-js-objects

Comment: Just access the data on the click event. Could you show how far you have come with a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=KGzkPoszgQ

Comment: I have added the .tsv file where the .css should go. I didn't know where to add it. But if you go to line 60 in the Javascript file you will see I have added the on.click event which currently works. Getting the event to click to an address is where I have been failing.