# GET request when clicking on D3.js node text

Tags: d3.js, hyperlink, get

I would like to make the text in the D3.js nodes submit a GET request upon click.

The jsfiddle for the code can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/ft5107wo/2/
I would like the GET request to be on the id key in node's JSON.

I have attempted [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104681/hyperlinks-in-d3-js-objects), but it did not work.

The relevant code for creating the rectangles and appending node text is from lines 191 to 218, and is as follows:

```
// Create the node rectangles.
nodes.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("height", 40)
    .attr("width", 40)
    .attr("id", function (d) {
    return d.id;
})
    .attr("display", function (d) {
    if (d.hidden) {
        return "none"
    } else {
        return ""
    };
})
    .attr("x", kx)
    .attr("y", ky);

// Create the node text label.
nodes.append("text")
    .text(function (d) {
    return d.name;
}).attr("transform", "translate(0," + 5 + ")")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("x", tx)
    .attr("y", ty)
    .attr("dy", 0)
.call(wrap, 40);
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out one needs to use [this hack](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/d3-js/Sh4ysLFBMRQ/hHjzBP0bX1oJ) to have it work correctly and avoid problems with namespaces.