# Assign hyperlink attribute to svg element not working

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am trying to follow the advice laid out in this post's answer and comments: [Hyperlinks in d3.js objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104681/hyperlinks-in-d3-js-objects) to add hyperlinks to circles in a d3.js bubble graph. **[Here's](http://sunnysideworks.nyc/d3/add_link/) where I am trying to do this**, and here's the original [bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269) I am trying to modify. As you can see all I've done is the following:

1. Replace `<html>` tag with: `<html xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">`
2. Insert this code right after creation of `var node`

   `node.append("svg:a").
   attr("xlink:href", function(d){return "http://www.google.com";});`

I am using Chrome and Firefox to test the page, and I don't see a hyperlink in either. Following some comments on the answer, I have tried:

1. Removing the `html` namespace declaration
2. Using `node.append("a")`

**I don't see any results with any of these options**, though I have been clearing my browser cache and using multiple computers to make sure I am seeing the fresh code. **What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<a>` has no content so it has no click area. You need to make something a child of the `<a>` nodes.