# Making only text in the nodes clickable in directed graph using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, directed-graph

I was looking at this example:
http://bl.ocks.org/cjrd/6863459

I need to make the only text clickable and when clicked it should lead to some hyperlink.

How would one able to do that in this particular case? I tried using [Hyperlinks in d3.js objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104681/hyperlinks-in-d3-js-objects)

Above example has helped me in only clicking the nodes. However I dont want to be redirected by clicking anywhere on the circle. I want only my text should be clickable as I am loosing the "drag" property of directed graph when whole circle is clickable.
I added namespace `<html xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">` to html file. Also, I modified the data to as

```
{"nodes":[{"title":"node 1","id":0,"x":935,"y":100, "url":"http://google.com"},{"title":"node 2","id":1,"x":644,"y":418, "url":"http://google.com"}, {"title":"node 3","id":2,"x":700,"y":500, "url":"http://google.com"}],"edges":[{"source":1,"target":0}]}
```

and edited d3 drawing code where you append nodes for each data element 
but it didnt help. Any help ?

Thanking you very much.

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff, I have edited my question, is it still similar to the question you mentioned?

Comment: Yes, you would apply this click handler only to the `text` elements and not anything else.