# d3js: `xlink:href` is not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to implement `href` to d3js chart as explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104681/hyperlinks-in-d3-js-objects) and [here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8150631). I added one simple `href` to [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304) d3js bar chart but it's not working. Here is my code: 
I imported `xlink` in `html`:

```
<myatr xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

</myatr>
```

and this is my part of d3js code,

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("xlink:href",function(d){return "www.google.com";});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to append the `a` tag too. Try this:

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("a")
      .attr("xlink:href", "www.google.com")
    .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); })
```